# DVI-D to VGA monitor, image no longer fills screen

Tags: display, vga, dvi

I have a DVI-D output on my graphics card going through an active adapter to a VGA monitor. This worked fine until I accidentally hit auto adjust on the monitor and now the image won't fill the screen, even with max pixel clock.

I've tried using a fullscreen sync pattern (http://randysimons.nl/125,english/131,tft-sync-pattern/) and auto adjusting again to no avail. I have no idea what else I can try.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Have you tried manually adjusting the image size? If it is an LCD monitor, have you tried setting the display resolution on the computer to match the native resolution of the monitor?

Comment: Thanks for your response. The desktop resolution is the same as the native resolution of the monitor. Unfortunately my monitor has no controls for manually scaling the image; just horizontal and vertical offset, and pixel clock and phase controls.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow unplugging and replugging the monitor cable from the DVI-D/VGA adapter with the computer running, then using auto adjust seems to have fixed everything. The adapter is a StarTech DVI2VGAE, I don't know if this solution is specific to the adapter or not.